# How to fix Error "'@ionic-enterprise/auth' is not in the npm registry."

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

while installing auth0 in ionic I'm facing this error.

```
ionic cordova plugin add @ionic-enterprise/auth-connect --variable AUTH_URL_SCHEME=com.company.app
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I think auth-connect plugin is only available for enterprise users. As I am also facing this same issue, and I looking for solution to integrate auth0 in ionic project for native apps.

Comment: @Divya, yeah I'm able to solve this problem later.Don't follow the demo from ionic docs instead follow them from auth0 docs

Comment: I have also checked docs provided by auth0. I think I am making some mistake in callback url's structure. I am getting this error after login: "Callback url" mismatch. Could you help me with what structure did you follow to make this working?

Comment: Add proper "Allowed Callback URIs" in the auth0 app `YOUR_PACKAGE_ID://APPNAME.auth0.com/cordova/YOUR_PACKAGE_ID/callback`

Answer (score 0):

The package `@ionic-enterprise/auth` is only available for subscriptors.

See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4359